# How to create Test App for Amazon Seller Central without paying monthly fee

Tags: amazonsellercentral

I need developer account on Amazon Seller Central so I can work with their API. It needs adding credit card and it shows $39.90 monthly fee, that is so much money for me. Is there option to make free developer account or sandbox to test Amazon API??

Comment: I presume you are referring to [Amazon Seller Central](https://sell.amazon.com/tools/seller-central)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi I mean on that... I need developer account so I can test API

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a free option to test Amazon's API. It's called the "Amazon MWS Sandbox." The sandbox environment allows you to test your application's integration with Amazon's Marketplace Web Service (MWS) without incurring any charges. You can use the sandbox to test your code, verify that it's working correctly, and debug any issues before you switch to live data. To get started, sign up for a sandbox account on the Amazon MWS Developer Documentation page.